# Did I give the right advice to my father about his 401k being down?

Tags: united-states, 401k

My dad has seen recently that I have taken an interest in finance and he asked me what he could do about his 401k being down.

So I said the US is currently in a recession and now you should put in more money while prices are low and use DCA (dollar cost averaging). He said why not move his portfolio to bonds for the time being because it hurts to see that his money keeps decreasing.

I personally don't know if that was a good idea or not. I just said it's hard to predict the market and buying and selling within one year might result in higher taxes. It's best to ride it out since you are only going to take the money out by 65 (50 now)

Did I say anything erroneous?

Comment: I would simply say: do you want to buy low and sell high, or would you rather sell low? but with the caveat that depending on his age, locking in a little below the top so far might be better than an unknown future

Comment: +1 especially for "stay the course". If he has an investment strategy, he may want to rebalance to get back to that mix; rebalancing is itself a form of "buy low, sell high". If he doesn't have a strategy, see other answers about developing one; the 401k may offer advisors to help with that, and they can also check that the strategy is still appropriate for this stage of his life.  If he is in a target date funds, those rebalance to their strategy AND adjust the strategy automatically and he can just let it do its job.

Comment: OMG please help your dad! "Jumping out of assets because things are low and they have hurt feelings in their tummy" is how people lose their retirements.  Because then, when stocks go back up, they move out of bonds and back into stocks, and they're "selling low buying high".

Comment: What does DCA have to do with this?  Does he have a large lump sum to invest?

Comment: @Kevin DCA is a misnomer, it's more like asset rebalancing (from cash into stonks when stonks are down). Though you can rebalance with either DCA or lump sums.

Comment: In the future, "I'm not sure, but let me try and look into it and get back to you" is probably wiser than offering un-/under-informed advice and then checking whether it was right.

Comment: How old is your father, and how soon does he epxpect to start withdrawing from the 401k?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Did I say anything erroneous?

> I personally don't know if that was a good idea or not. I said its
> hard to predict the market and buying and selling within one year
> might result in higher taxes. Its best to ride it out since you are
> only going to take the money out by 65.

The one thing incorrect in your advice was regarding taxes. If the money is inside an IRA or a 401(k) or similar type of retirement fund, then there are no taxes due in the near term if you sell some or all of your investment for a profit, as long as the money stays inside the retirement account. Pulling the money from the 401(k) is probably a taxable event, and may even trigger penalties.

Many (most? all?) 401(k) programs have different investment options. They can range from 100% stocks, to 100% bonds. They even have ones that automatically become more conservative as the owner get closer to retirement age. They have ones that focus on the US market, and ones that focus on international markets. Some even let you pick individual stocks, others limit you to index funds.

We don't know enough about your dad's situation to know what investment mix makes sense for his family.

> So I said the US us currently in a recession and now you should put in
> more money while prices are low and use DCA.

If the mix is correct then the prices being down, does allow for the purchase of more shares, which can help if prices go back up. Putting money into a 401(k) every payday, is a form of DCA.

> He said why not move his portfolio to bonds for the time being because
> it hurts to his money keep decreasing.

It is unclear if your Dad should change his mix of investments, or increase how much of each paycheck goes into the 401(k).

Regarding changing the mix, that is a form of timing the market. Believing that you need to radically change the mix of investments now, to make money in the near term, and then change the mix again when the economy returns to "normal"; means that you have to guess correctly twice. Otherwise you can miss the gains that would have occurred if you had done nothing.

It might make sense to have a fiduciary fee only planner review the mix of investments to see if they make sense for the long term. They would also look at the entire financial picture including non-401(k) accounts, insurance and the like.

Note: you mention age 65. The penalty for withdraws goes away at 59.5. There are other age levels that can impact pensions, social security, and required minimum distributions.

Comment: I know fidelity offers target retirement date funds and they will essentially transition from stocks to bonds and money market accounts the closer you get to the retirement date.  So if OPs father is in one of those type of funds and is within a decade of retirement, chances are he's already 60% or more in bonds.

Comment: I hate this phrase "that is a form of timing the market". Literally every form of "investing" is timing the market. Even saying "stonks generally go up" is timing the market because it's betting that the price now is quite low compared to what it will be in the future.

Comment: @user253751 Really? ... Not saying this is a good plan, per se, but what if the plan is to invest for the dividends? Is that "timing the market?" ... What about getting a rental property? Or P2P lending?

Comment: @svidgen if you are planning to hold something until it matures that is not so much timing (but still somewhat timing); but it is also not how people generally invest.

Comment: @user253751 "Literally every form of "investing" is timing the market." No, it's not. "Even saying "stonks generally go up" is timing the market because it's betting that the price now is quite low compared to what it will be in the future." That's not what "timing the market" means.

Answer (score 8):

> Did I say anything erroneous?

Technically, the US isn't currently in a recession (yet) although a lot of investors expect one some time in 2023/2024 but nobody knows for sure if/when that will happen. Also, there's typically a lag between bear markets/recessions, which is hard to predict.

The rest is up for debate:

> you should put in more money while prices are low and use DCA.

Generally good advice but it depends on his investment horizon, i.e. how much time does he have until he needs the funds. He'll need to consider his overall financial position before piling more money into equities.

> He said why not move his portfolio to bonds for the time being because it hurts to his money keep decreasing.

On one hand, yields are high right now but credit spreads have been widening, so high-quality bonds are an option. However, in the long run it pays to be patient rather than selling low and buying something else. If it's painful to watch, maybe don't look.

> I personally don't know if that was a good idea or not. I said its hard to predict the market

Correct, we don't know.

> buying and selling within one year might result in higher taxes.

Short-term capital gains are typically taxed at a higher rate than long-term capital gains for regular brokerage accounts. The same isn't true for 401(k) and other tax-advantaged accounts. AFAIK, there's no tax implication when you buy/sell within the 401(k) without withdrawing the money. In any case, I wouldn't put the tax cart before the investment horse.

> Its best to ride it out since you are only going to take the money out by 65.

Not sure when that will be (next year, in five years, 15 years?) or what you mean by that.

Comment: It isn't true that the US isn't in a recession. A recession can only be determined (with certainty) after the fact. So we could be in one and only find out 6 months from now. Given the state of the economy, it would not be wrong to estimate that we indeed are in a recession.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to clarify (it's not really "wrong" but misunderstood) - DCA is not a *strategy*. It's a *natural effect* of contributing to retirement or other investment accounts periodically, like, say, when you get paid.

There is not fundamental reason why DCA would provide better returns than lump-sum investing. In fact, since the general trend for markets is to go *up*, more often than not, lump sum investing would be *better* than periodic investing.

Take now for example - you suggest that he should start buying now, presumably because you expect the market to go back up. Why not just invest it all now? Why wait and invest it slowly over time as the market recovers? What mathematical advantage does DCA give you? Sure if the market goes down for a bit you would be buying at a slightly lower spot, but if the general trend is to go up, wouldn't you want to buy *before* it goes up?  Anything else is trying to "time the market" which is just guessing at that point.

Comment: The mathematical advantage is lower variability. The purpose of DCA isn't to outperform lump-sum investing on average, it's to reduce volatility - every individual is an N of 1, so individuals must consider variability in addition to the average of their approach. The outcome of lump-sum investing is more variable, as it's highly dependent on when you start. DCA may not provide better returns, but it will be less volatile - anyone starting DCA this week will see basically the same return 5 years from now, but future returns on a lump sum investment can depend on the precise time you bought.

Comment: You can also do DCA deliberately. You can say that market volatility is high right now, so instead of investing 20% of your paycheck now, you will invest 5% a week for 4 weeks.

Comment: and, all investing is timing the market.

Comment: @user253751 I kind of get where you are coming from but I don't think it's helpful.  'Timing the market' is a term of art and has a very specific meaning that isn't "buying when you have money".

Comment: @JimmyJames it means buying when you think the market is low and selling when you think it is high, yes? Buying when you have the money carries the assumption that you think the market is always currently low, compared to the future.

Comment: "However, in the long run it pays to be patient rather than selling low and buying something else." <- I like to say: You have to sell *before* it crashes. After is too late.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "The mathematical advantage is lower variability." In exchange for lower returns. The whole point of investing is to accept risk in exchange for returns. If you don't like that, don't invest. There's no alpha in DCA, it's pure beta reduction.

Comment: @user253751 "[timing the market] means buying when you think the market is low and selling when you think it is high, yes?" No, it means trying to get alpha by trying to guess when the market is deviating from its risk-adjusted value.

Comment: @user253751 "Buying when you have the money carries the assumption that you think the market is always currently low, compared to the future."  It means you expect a return on the market over the long-term and you **not** timing your purchases based on changes in momentum.  It's literally the opposite of timing the market.  I don't think it's always wrong to time the market: I put extra cash into the market near the bottom of 2009, for example.  But we start calling every purchase 'timing' it would simply make the word meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Seems overall good, but the best advice for someone stuck in this mode of thinking is is "change the delivery address for your retirement account statements to someone who will throw them in the garbage for you, and stop watching cable financial news".

There is no way in which watching this stuff can lead to financial wins, but it can lead to financial ruin if you act on the "hurt" and "feeling" of "losing money" by selling low and then getting stuck buying high. If you're prone to act irrationally like that, the only winning move is to deny yourself the information with which to do so.